# What exactly does OpenSSL's s_client do when using the "-CApath" option?

Tags: openssl

I've come across an interesting behavior of `s_client` when trying to debug some SSL issues we are having with a client's web server.

If I do

`openssl s_client -servername 'www.delinat.com' -connect www.delinat.com:443`

`s_client` gives me `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`.

I guess that means that by default, it is not using any trusted root certificates, because that's what the `-CApath` and `-CAfile` options are here for, right?

But consider this:

`openssl s_client -servername 'www.delinat.com' -connect www.delinat.com:443 -CApath foo`

This command will return `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`, but there is no directory `foo`!

It looks as if giving an inexistant path will somehow force `s_client` to use default root certificates.

But giving the `-CApath` option without a value will produce an error.

Can anyone shed some light on this behavior? Also, **which** root certificates is `s_client` using in the second case?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: ***`openssl s_client -servername 'www.delinat.com' -connect www.delinat.com:443 -CApath foo` ... will return `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`*** - confirmed on OpenSSL 1.0.2c. That appears to be a security bug. I took the liberty of emailing the folks at OpenSSL and citing this question. Good find.

Comment: Thanks @jww! I also voted to close the question.

Comment: I just talked with Matt Caswell from the project. He could not duplicate. I then looked at my setup, and found it was using Macport's OpenSSL. I then used my copy of OpenSSL in `/usr/local/ssl`, and it failed, too. ***Question***: are you using Macports?

Comment: No, this is using OpenSSL 1.0.1e on Debian Wheezy 7.8 (specifically, version `1.0.1e-2+deb7u17`).

Comment: I could also reproduce this on Debian Jessie 8.1, using OpenSSL `1.0.1k-3`.

Comment: Macports was provided the information with a post to their User's mailing list at [Bug in openssl s_client verification](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2015-July/038891.html). You should file bug reports with the Debian folks. `$ apt-cache show openssl | grep Maintainer` will provide the email contacts.

Comment: I think that happens because in apps/s_client.c:1345 the default verify paths are always added even if `-CAfile` or `-CApath` are given. Whether these paths are relevant depends on the values of `X509_CERT_FILE` and `X509_CERT_DIR` in `crypto/cryptlib.h`, which depend on `OPENSSLDIR`, which changes depending on the `--openssldir=...` configure switch. My guess is Debian sets that, but that copy in `/usr/local` doesn't. Consequently, s_client behaves as designed (even though the behaviour is weird). Lessons learned: don't trust or rely on what s_client tells you. (I checked 1.0.2c)

Comment: Yep: https://sources.debian.net/src/openssl/1.0.2c-1/debian/rules/#L29 and https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/openssl/Portfile?marks=48#L45 and a copy built without `--openssldir` fails with return code 20. This is not a bug.

Comment: OK, so NeverPanic and I got to have a sidebar with Matt Caswell about this. It appears this is default behavior from the library. So, I was wrong and  NeverPanic was right. With that said, I still think its a security bug because the following makes it appear Google is certifying Microsoft properties (it really attenuates the problem): `openssl s_client -connect www.microsoft.com:443 -tls1 -servername www.microsoft.com -CAfile Google-CA.pem`.

Comment: A work around is available for OpenSSL proper. Specify both `-CApath` and `-CAfile`: `openssl s_client -connect www.microsoft.com:443 ... -CAfile Google-CA.pem -CApath /dev/null`. Specifying both `path` and `file` allows you to effectively remove the defaults (if any), and that makes it expected behavior. However, the Debian patch overrrides the behavior, so the override never occurs. That is, Debian ensures the defaults are always available, so you cannot fail (in this situation). Debian provides unexpected behavior (as if Google appearing to certify Microsoft is expected :)

Comment: Thanks for all the insights! Something I still don't quite get is why the verification is failing if I give *neither* `CApath` nor `CAfile`. Shouldn't the defaults also be used in this case?